# Android:Horizontal scroll view at the top, load part of the screen

Tags: android, memory, load, horizontalscrollview

I'm a android newbie. Recently I created a activity which has a HorizontalScrollView at the top of the page with a collection of images with onClickListener. Each image in the HorizontalScrollView represents some listviews and imageviews.

Currently, after I click on any image in the top HorizontalScrollView bar, the program fires up another new activity. This is definitely not very efficient, since the HorizontalScrollView at the top doesn't change but we need to load it everytime.

I wonder if there is any way I can only load part of the screen after I click an imageView at the top bar(HorizontalScrollView)

Thanks in advance!

Jake

Comment: Look into `Fragment` and `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use a LayoutInflater in the src code to load another xml layout into the already running activity for example.

Comment: This is *not* a good idea. While it will work, any references to views you've already obtained are lost.